# How to get both the quotient and the remainder in Python? (in one line of code)

Tags: python

Is there a function that returns both the quotient and remainder? Say I want to divide 11/5, is there a function that returns both 2 (quotient) and 1 (remainder) (in any data structure, but preferably a tuple or a list). Like this:

```
>>print(foo(11,5))

>>[2,1]
```

I've seen some with other languages on SO but I couldn't find one for Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod), the built-in providing exactly this functionality:

```
 divmod(11, 5)
 # (2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, is this function built-in?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need.